# strategies for error handling in a c# async lambda world?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous

I used to write thick c# client code that would throw exceptions down in the engine room (network failure say) and expect somebody above me to deal with it. Eventually bubbling up to an appwide try/catch that would handle the leftovers ("Unexpected exception in foo bar, click for details, contact support...."), plus maybe a appdomain wide unhandled exception handler just in case.

Now I am writing a 'thick' client in Silverlight and I don't know what to do anymore. Large amounts of my engine room code run as network event driven callbacks, and I then invoke a lambda supplied to me by the original caller; but they are long gone. I cant throw an exception at them, there is no stack to bubble up. I can't force them to unwind. They are still in a pending state (whatever that might mean for that particular async invoke).

I see AsyncEventCompletedArgs with its RaiseExceptionIfNeeded trick. Using this seems to expose my low level plumbing to the higher level code (think MVVM , MVC, ...). I want to help the upper level code 'do the right thing' by default, like they did in the good old sync/exception driven days. But this doesnt help. They read the result from the AsyncArgs instance, that throws and the call back dies, leaving them still logically dangling

Anyway - hope this makes sense. Does anybody have any designs, experience that they want to share. What do any of the SL MVVM, MVC frameworks do?

Note - I am not talking about the fancy new Async stuff in c#5 (would that help at all?)

(Probably going to get closed as not specific enough, too subjective, etc, sigh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the caller to supply a lambda for the successful completion, and also a lambda that takes an exception for the cases where an exception is caught in your code.

Reactive Extensions allows this when subscribing to the observable.

Something along the lines of:

```
asyncCall.Subscribe(result => DoSomething(result), ex => Oops(ex));
```

Comment: this is what I was coming down to. My concern was that at my upper 'pure semantic' layers I was exposing too much plumbing detail

Comment: I don't think it's plumbing detail to have 'execute this on success' and 'execute this on failure'... if you were able to throw the exception in the right place it's what would get put in the catch block anyway

Comment: I watched bart's presentation on RX. Makes me think I am being too timid: I really need to completely invert my application, rather than making a 'normal' app that just has async IO.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement includes significant parallel outstanding Asynchronous operations then don't bother reading anymore of this answer.  However if the operations are invoked sequentially (one not invoked until another has completed) which it sounds like it might be, then you might find the stuff alluded to here mildly useful.

Handling Asynchronous code in Silverlight is subject in which I take a keen interest.  I've written several blogs about what I call the `AsynchOperationService` that enables code to be written using a simple synchronous looking sequential style and includes good support for error handling.

Pick them out from this [list](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/category/12040.aspx).

Rx may be an option it does look like it would be powerful.  However it is complex, it was originally designed to handle a stream of incoming events.  I'm not convinced (although I admit my research is still shallow) that its a good fit for the "Start something, respond later to that something finishing" operation.

Personally I like things to be simple and straight forward but its evident that I need to completely change the way I code to properly include the power of Rx and I'm fairly certain the resulting code is not going to be that easy to read.

Whereas with `AsyncOperationService` has a very light foot print and once I've created a few useful one-liner functions the resulting sequence of code is quite straight-forward to read.

So whats the catch?  Well there is one and its either exactly what you need or works exactly against what you need.   The approach works on the assumption that a series of async operation need to completed in sequence.  If your requirement is for significant parallel operations then in its current form `AsyncOperationService` is not for you (although that may change).

Comment: I have to say that the use of yield return is very clever. I would never have thought of it

Comment: I think he means Reactive Extensions for 'Rx'

Answer (score 0):

I use code of following structure to handle exceptions problems async:

```
        void ClientAsyncOperationCompleted(object sender, AsyncOperationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null) {
                //Normal execution path
            }
            else {
                //you can put your structured exception handling code here around e.Error
                if(e.Error is ConcreteException) {
                   //concrete exception handling
                }
                else {
                   //general exception handling
                } 
            }
        }
```

If method is executed asynchronously there is no way to get a synchronous exception throw, except if we wrap async method and  synchronize its execution using some thread synchronization construct like `ManualResetEvent` for example. So if we accept that we handle exception asyncronously, inside AsyncCompleted you can call your desired Oops(Exception e) method like this:

```
void ClientAsyncOperationCompleted(object sender, AsyncOperationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null) {
       //Normal execution path
    }
    else {
       Oops(e.Error);
    }
}
```

thats without Rx which is pretty complex, but powerful.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the Exception back to the UI thread. You still want to throw up till someone handles it like before but you have to capture it at the top level of the thread and pass it back to the main thread and handle it there like usual. There are a couple of ways of doing this, the easiest in Silverlight is to use the BackgroundWorker but the raw way to do it is to basically provide a callback to all async methods that return values or errors. Something like this:

```
DoAsync(
  () => BackgroundThreadWork(), // executed on background thread
  result => {                   // executed on UI thread
    if(result.Error != null)
      throw result.Error;
    HandleResultOnUIThread(result.Value);
  });
```

Here is an example of a very simple async action queue that could probably be converted into a Silverlight friendly version pretty easily:

[Simple ActionQueue in MetaSharp](http://metasharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c0cdc86dc3e#src/MetaSharp.Integration.VisualStudio/Grammar/ActionQueue.cs)

I am using a queue because it allows me to guarantee the order of work being done on background threads. When you have a bunch of async operations it's really easy to get into race conditions and such, a queue is an excellent structure for guaranteeing the order of their execution even though they are all actually async. The queueGroup is for actions that you also want to be parallel as well as async.